# Can Unit 3 have numbers in category names?

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

Can category names have numbers with NUnit 3.4.1 when executed as tags in SpecFlow scenarios?

Comment: Have you tried this just using plain nunit? All specflow does is generate nunit tests so all the usual nunit rules apply, nothing specific to specflow here. Please remove the teamcity tag, this is unrelated to teamcity

Answer (score 0):

You can check the CategoryAttribute in the Designer generated code

It seems that it is ok:
@3dasd

become:

NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute("3dasd")